# Is there any way to attach javascript file in myapplicationUI in VAADIN 6

Tags: javascript, vaadin

Is there any way to attach javascript file in myapplicationUI class like we have `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("alert('hello javascript')");`. I don't want to execute only 1 line, instead i need to run whole file. So how can i achieve my goal.
note: I am using VAADIN 6
 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I got you wrong but due to missing reputation I am not able to comment yet.

Can't you use the @JavaScript Annotation?

See: 
https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.6/com/vaadin/annotations/JavaScript.html
https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+a+JavaScript+component+

Comment: How can i make this blunder. Actually i need to do it in vaadin 6. This javascript annotation is in vaadin 7.

Comment: Did you just add the Vaddin 6 info or did I miss it...?
A Vaadin 6 solution can be found here: 
https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/791748/791747

Comment: Thank you very much. i got a way (for the viewers facing same problem). i initialized all functions in a script and add it through servlet. Then call those functions in Application where needed.